# What are the usage scenarios of logical delete column and delete record table?

Tags: mysql

such as a table A

```sql
create table A(,
  id int NOT_NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  is_deleted tinyint(1) NOT_NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

It uses the `is_deleted` column instead of the delete statement

But there is another case, which is to put the deleted data into a separate record table
ARecord

```sql
create table ARecord(
  id int NOT_NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  delete_time datetime,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

The deletion here refers to the deletion in the macro sense.
i.e. expired, invalid, graduated, dismissed.
Essentially a huge drop in lookup frequency

So what are the use cases for these two? When to use column? When to use table?

Comment: Message to those who see this as closable due to "opinion-based".  Think of it as trying to tap into the _experience_ of those who have pursued the question and have determined an answer.

Comment: This is just a subset of a larger category of slowly changing dimensions, for which there are many approaches; without the OP describing the exact use case it's impossible to decide which is most appropriate.

Comment: @mustaccio - "Soft delete" is a common practice; it is every provided as an option by some platforms.  (I say that the OP adequately defined the 'use case'.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

(This Answer is based on **Experience**, not just **Opinion**.)

Cases for "soft" delete (flag `is_deleted`, or even `deleted DEFAULT NULL`)

- The table is "small" -- under, say, 50K rows and/or
- The number of "deleted" rows is low -- under, say, 1/4 of the rows.

Else move the "deleted" rows to another table.

A 3rd approach is to `PARTITION` on the deleted column.  But this is not necessarily any better than your 2-table approach.

Comment: Would the down-voter like to provide a different argument?